# Transfer calculated value from stat_smooth to other geom like linerange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question about ggplot2.

I want to **connect** data point with ols result via vertical line, like the code listed below.

Can I transfer `..y..`, the value calculated by `stat_smooth`, to `geom_linerange` directly?

I tried `stat_smooth(..., geom = "linerange", mapping(aes(ymin=pmin(myy, ..y..), ymax=pmax(myy,..y..))` but it is not the result I want.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(myx = 1:10,
                 myy = c(1:10) * 5 + 2 * rnorm(10, 0, 1))
lm.fit <- lm("myy~myx", data = df)
pred <- predict(lm.fit)
ggplot(df, aes(myx, myy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_linerange(mapping = aes(ymin = pmin(myy, pred),
                               ymax = pmax(myy, pred)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat_smooth` evaluates the values at `n` evenly spaced points, with `n = 80` by default. These points may not coincide with the original x values in your data frame.

Since you are calculating predicted values anyway, it would probably be more straightforward to add that back to your data frame and plot all geom layers based on that as your data source, for example:

```
df$pred <- pred

ggplot(df, aes(myx, myy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = myy, ymax = pred))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Is it possible to make ..y..  coincide with original x by changing some default parameters?
I used to think it was not necessary to recalculate fitted value outside stat_smooth again.